# Show current location button not showing in react native maps, using expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

Maps tiles working, but button current location not showing
[maps display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLzCx.jpg)

```
         <MapView
            ref={mapView}
            style={{
                flex: 1
            }}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            showsTraffic={true}
            showsCompass={true}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            initialRegion={region}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            showsScale={true}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem because active location permission not active,
using expo will be like this

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
const Map = () => {

    const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({
        latitude: 10,
        longitude: 10,
    });

  React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
                return;
            }
            foregroundSubscrition = Location.watchPositionAsync(
                {
                    // Tracking options
                    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
                    distanceInterval: 10,
                },
                location => {
                    console.log(location)
                    let cor = {
                        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: location.coords.longitude,

                    }
                    setPosition(cor);
                }
            )
     
        })();
    }, []);
})
```